# Deleting, uncreating or unflagging a directory as a Repository

Tags: linux, shell, fedora, repository

While learning Linux I have followed the link [Creating a Yum Repository](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Creating_a_Yum_Repository.html). I've installed the `createrepo` and everything went OK (I guess). Now I want to undo it by deleting, uncreating, or unflagging the directory from being a Repository. Can someone help me please with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can just delete the folder or the subfolder `repodata`. The repo is not registred by default...

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer i was telling myself the same thing , but i was wondering if their is a more adequate and "beautiful" way to do it.

Comment: Well... I don't think there is a more beautifull way. Just because this command would only delete the created metadata (the subfolder `repodata` and nothing more). So, I would be surprised, if there is something. But, I am not a Fedora-Repo-Creater-Professional. So, I might be wrong...